# Obtaining p-values for RDA analysis using R package "vegan"

Tags: r, vegan, rda

I am conducting a Redundancy Analysis using R package "vegan". I would like to obtain p-values (or alternatively t-values) for the analysis to assess the significance of my predictor variables. I'm able to generate p-values using the anova function, separately for each RDA axis (axis) and each predictor (terms):

```
model<-rda(precip ~ SOI + IOD + AAO, predictors)

anova_axis<-anova(model,by="axis")
anova_terms<-anova<-anova(model,by="term")


#### Outputs ####

Model: rda(formula = precip ~ SOI + IOD + AAO, data = predictors)
          Df Var    F         N.Perm Pr(>F)   
RDA1      1  640315 6.1841    199    0.005 **
RDA2      1  255421 2.4669    199    0.010 **
RDA3      1   75211 0.7264     99    0.710   
Residual  25 2588537  


Model: rda(formula = precip ~ SOI + IOD + AAO, data = predictors)
          Df    Var      F     N.Perm Pr(>F)   
SOI       1  435080 4.2020     99     0.01 **
IOD       1  419880 4.0552     99     0.01 **
SAM_AAO   1  115987 1.1202     99     0.23   
Residual 25 2588537
```

However, what I really need is p-values for each predictor, for each RDA axis. So a table of like this:

```
Predictor    RDA1    RDA2    RDA3
SOI          xxx     xxx     xxx
IOD          xxx     xxx     xxx
AAO          xxx     xxx     xxx
```

Does anyone know how and whether this is possible to obtain? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It is not possible in a meaningful way.

Comment: To expand on @JariOksanen's comment, to do this would require the derivation of the so-called *canonical coefficients*. The are not the normal regression coefficients you might get from a weighted regression of the mean 0, unit variance, explanatory variables on to the WA site scores for each site on each RDA axis. Importantly, canonical coefficients have larger variance than regression coefficients & hence the Student *t*-like approach of "testing" coefficients is not appropriate. The Canoco 5 manual suggests *t*-values < |2.1| indicate variables that contribute little to the fit...

Comment: ...hence one could use this to indicate variables that could be removed without much changing the canonical eigenvalues, but you can do this already with forward selection and the types of permutation allowed by `anova.cca`. *t*-values may be of use in certain biplot-like graphical analyses of the results, such as the *t*-value biplot, ...

Comment: ...but there still be dragons and I would suggest that if you know how to handle these *t*-values appropriately, you are capable of computing the required stats yourself; they are just a weighted least squares fit of the *p* explanatory variables on the sites scores that are WA of the species scores, all of which can be derived from the objects `rda()` returns. However, as you are asking for us to turn these *t* stats into *p*-values, heed @JariOksanen's advice that this is not possible in a way that would be meaningful to you or anyone else looking at your results.

Comment: @GavinSimpson gave out so much that I may reveal the rest: vegan has a canned function to do this: check `as.mlm`. This can give you the coefficients @GavinSimpson mentioned, and even their standard deviations, t-values and p-values. Read its documentation which warns you against using them. Believe me: they are not meaningful and you really do not need them (although you say so).